# Elementor/Wordpress form field with cutoff time using Twig

Tags: twig

So I have a form on my website which needs a cutoff time, I use a plugin that makes this possible with Twig but I cant seem to find out how it works. I made it work to exclude todays day but now I need to add a cutoff time at 15:30 that its not possible to make a appointment for the day after.

I will provide some screenshots of my settings right now, I hope someone can help me!

Thanks in advance!

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dt8b.png)

I tried using:

```
{% if 'now'|date('YmdHi') > 'now'|date('Ymd1530') %}
    {{'+2 day'|date('Y-m-d')}}
{% else %}
    {{'+1 day'|date('Y-m-d')}}
{% endif %}
```

But that didn't work for me, maybe something is wrong with the date or time format?

Answer (score -3):

The `filter` date is used to format/output a valid `DateTime` or `DateTime` expression. If you want to create a valid `DateTime` you would need to resort to the `date` function, e.g.

```
{% set date = date('now'|date('d-m-Y')~' 15:30:00') %}
```

This will create a new instance of `DateTime` with the current date and time set to `15:00:00`

Furthermore, you shouldn't use the string notation to compare dates, you are better off with using the unix timestamp

```
{% if 'now'|date('U') > date('now'|date('d-m-Y')~' 15:30:00').format('U') %}
    {{'+2 day'|date('Y-m-d')}}
{% else %}
    {{'+1 day'|date('Y-m-d')}}
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/nk85ly)

Comment: Im not very experienced with this type of code so im trying to understand ;) with this link you can check how it looks right now: mintdigitalagencym40.sg-host.com/container-ophalen